# How to pipe "member of" to csv in Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory, activedirectorymembership

I am attempting to get a list of information about what groups a selected user is a member of. I found a script on here earlier that seemed to be of use:

```
    Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Users,DC=Domain,DC=Local" -Filter *  |  foreach-object {
        write-host "User:" $_.Name -foreground green
        Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $_.SamAccountName |  foreach-object {
        write-host "Member Of:" $_.name
        } 
    }
```

However this script is not doing the job. I need to take the data gathered from this script and export to a CSV. I have attempted to pipeline Export-Csv in various places through the script (last curly bracket, second to last curly bracket, and before the curly brackets) but I'm met with no success.

Any other ideas? I attempted another script that I wrote:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Users,DC=Domain,DC=Local"
-Properties name,SamAccountName | select name,SamAccountName | Export-Csv "C:\Path.csv"
```

And this one as well

```
    Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Users,DC=Domain,DC=Local" -Properties name,SamAccountName | select name,SamAccountName | Export-Csv "C:\Path.csv"
```

Neither of which was successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you intend on the final CSV to be formatted.  In the first code you are using "write-host" which will only write that content to the screen. You may want to take each of those and pipe them into a csv manually.  Using your code here is an example.

```
"`"User`",`"Group`"" | out-file export.csv

    Get-ADUser -SearchBase "CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local" -Filter *  |  foreach-object {
        write-host "User:" $_.Name -foreground green
        $u = $_.samaccountName
        Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $_.SamAccountName |  foreach-object {
        write-host "Member Of:" $_.name
        $g = $_.name
        "`"$u`",`"$g`"" | out-file export.csv -append
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I tweaked the formatting a bit. Thank you very much